# How to find the exact intersection between two arrays without removing duplications in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have two arrays of numbers `arr1` and `arr2`. I want to find the intersection between them and each element in the result must appear as many times as it shows in **Both arrays**.

After 2 hours of trying, I made this solution but it does not cover all cases:

### Code

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums1
 * @param {number[]} nums2
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var intersect = function (nums1, nums2) {
    if (nums1.length == nums2.length) {
        if (nums1.includes(nums2) && nums2.includes(nums1)) {
            return nums1[0];
        }
        if (nums1.includes(nums2)) {
            return nums2.filter((v) => nums1.includes(v));
        } else {
            return nums1.filter((v) => nums2.includes(v));
        }
    }
    if (nums1.length < nums2.length)
        return nums1.filter((v) => nums2.includes(v));
    if (nums2.length < nums1.length)
        return nums2.filter((v) => nums1.includes(v));
};

console.log(intersect([1, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2]));
console.log(intersect([1, 2, 2, 1], [2]));
console.log(intersect([9, 4, 9, 8, 4], [4, 9, 5]));
console.log(intersect([2, 1], [1, 1])); // failed ( should be [1]
```

### Test 1 (passed)

- **Input :** nums1 = [1,2,2,1] , nums2 = [2,2]
- **Output**: [2,2]

### Test 2 (passed)

- **Input :** nums1 = [4,9,5], nums2 = [9,4,9,8,4]
- **Output**:  [4,9] or [9,4]

### Test 3 (failed)

- **Input :** nums1 = [3,1,2], nums2 = [1,1]
- **Output**:  [1,1]

Comment: please add the wanted results as well

Comment: "each element in the result must appear as many times as it shows in Both arrays."

Can you clarify what this means? If this were true, wouldn't test case #2 be wrong with `[4, 9]` since `4` appears three times in total across both arrays?

Comment: `nums1.includes(nums2)` is never true. `includes` checks for the presence of an individual element within the array, and `nums1` does not include `nums2` as an entry. For it to be true you'd need a nested array like `[1, 2, nums2]`. And it's an identity comparison, so even this wouldn't return true:  `nums1.includes(1, 2, [1,2,3])`, even if nums2 was `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen it's an intersection. So if `1` shows up in only one of the arrays, it's not in the output. If it shows up in both, it goes in the output. If it shows up twice in each array, it shows up in the output twice. If it shows three times in one array, but two times in the other, it's two times in the output. Again - this is [an intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection).

Comment: @VLAZ If that were true the third test case should return `[1]` as it does in OP's answer but they expect it to return `[1, 1]`. Unless that is a typo?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen no it *failed* and the output was `[1, 1]`.

Comment: @VLAZ If you run the snippet, you can see that the output is `[1]`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Wait, I didn't run the code. The output of `[1]` which it produces is correct. It's indeed incorrect to expect `[1, 1]`. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could count the items and filter the second array.

```js
const
    intersect = (nums1, nums2) => {
        const
            count = (c, i) => v => c[v] = (c[v] || 0) + i,
            counts = {};
            
        nums1.forEach(count(counts, 1));
        return nums2.filter((f => v => f(v) >= 0)(count(counts, -1)));
        
    };

console.log(intersect([1, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2]));
console.log(intersect([1, 2, 2, 1], [2]));
console.log(intersect([9, 4, 9, 8, 4], [4, 9, 5]));
console.log(intersect([2, 1], [1, 1])); // failed
```

Answer (score 2):

In pseudo-code, if

```
a1 = [9, 4, 9, 8, 4]
a2 = [4, 9, 4, 5, 4]
```

then compute counting hashes

```
h1 = { 9=>2, 4=>2, 8=>1 }
h2 = { 4=>3, 9=>1, 5=>1 }
```

Next, determine

```
common_keys = h1.keys intersect h2.keys
  #=> [9, 4, 8] intersect [4, 9, 5]
  #=> [9, 4]
```

Then

```
b = common_keys.map { |key| [key] repeat [h1[key], h2[key]].min }
  #=> = [[9], [4, 4]]
```

and lastly

```
b.flatten
  #=> [9, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to count the occurrences of each N in both arrays then filter:

```js
function frequency(nums) {
  return nums.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr]) {
      acc[curr]++;
    } else {
      acc[curr] = 1;

    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

var intersect = function(nums1, nums2) {
  const nums1Frequencies = frequency(nums1);
  const nums2Frequencies = frequency(nums2);

         // only consider unique elements from nums1 (we already counted occurrences)
  return Array.from(new Set(nums1))
           // determine how many of N should appear in the result
           .map(n => [n, Math.min(nums1Frequencies[n], nums2Frequencies[n])])
           // filter out N that were not in both arrays
           .filter(([n, min]) => !Number.isNaN(min))
           // create an Array containing the number of N that should go into the result
           .map(([n, min]) => Array(min).fill(n))
           // flatten nested arrays
           .flat()
};

console.log(intersect([1, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2]));        // [2, 2]
console.log(intersect([1, 2, 2, 1], [2]));           // [2]
console.log(intersect([9, 4, 9, 8, 4], [4, 9, 5]));  // [9, 4]
console.log(intersect([2, 1], [1, 1]));              // [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Single linear scan through both arrays to count occurrences followed by a linear scan of the result to extract the intersection.

This solution uses a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as it is safer when handling primitives. For example, if an array has mixed values: `[1, "1", 2]` these will be three distinct counts, as the map preserves the types of its keys.

```js
/**
 * Counts occurrences of each member of array
 * @param {any[]} arr - array of any values
 * @return {Map} a map of the breakdowns - each key is a unique item in the array  (SameValueZero comparison) and the values are the counts of occurrences
 */
const countMembers = arr => {
  const counts = new Map();
  
  for (const item of arr)
    counts.set(item, (counts.get(item) ?? 0) + 1);
    
  return counts;
};

/**
 * Merge maps where the keys intersect, skip keys that are only in one map
 * @param {Map} map1
 * @param {Map} map2
 * @param valueMergeCallback - determines how the values will be handled. Called with value from map1 and value from map2 as arguments
 * @return {Map} Map with keys that only show up in both map1 and map2 where the value is determined by valueMergeCallback
 */
const intersectMergeMaps = (map1, map2, valueMergeCallback) => {
  const result = new Map();
  
  for (const [key, value1] of map1) {
    if (!map2.has(key))
      continue;
      
    const value2 = map2.get(key);
    result.set(key, valueMergeCallback(value1, value2));
  }
 
  return result;
};

/**
 * Helper function that creates an array of repeated values
 * @param {*} value - item that will show up in array
 * @param {number} repeat - how many times it should appear in the array
 * @return array containing only value repeat number of times
 */ 
const repeatArray = (value, repeat) =>
  Array.from({length: repeat}, () => value);
  
  
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums1
 * @param {number[]} nums2
 * @return {number[]}
 */
const intersect = function (nums1, nums2) {
    const count1 = countMembers(nums1);
    const count2 = countMembers(nums2);
    
    const m = intersectMergeMaps(count1, count2, Math.min);
    
    return Array.from(m)
      .flatMap(([num, count]) => repeatArray(num, count));
};

console.log(intersect([1, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2]));
console.log(intersect([1, 2, 2, 1], [2]));
console.log(intersect([9, 4, 9, 8, 4], [4, 9, 5]));
console.log(intersect([2, 1], [1, 1]));


console.log(intersect([2, 1], [4, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Nina Scholz's solution works well but it has the following:**

## **Time complexity:** **67.08%**

## **space complexity:** **67.82%**

I tried to figure out the bug of my algorithm and found that I repeat the same **checks** repeatedly based on the arrays **lengths**.

So, instead of using `if/else` outside of the `filter` method I moved the condition inside the `filter` method.

I want to ignore the passed **checks**.

The only way I found is to remove that `value` from the `nums2`.

### Code

```
return nums1.filter(
        (value) => nums2.includes(value) && nums2.splice(nums2.indexOf(value), 1)
    );
};
```

### Result

## **Time complexity:** **96.98%**

## **space complexity:** **85.87%**

Comment: Erm, complexity isn't measured in percentages. It's described in terms of limits `O(n)` for example.